# Why is my pivot table showing different values than the table it's based on?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a simple table with names of employees and whether or not they've met a certain criteria ('yes' or 'no' in a column).  I've created a pivot table using insert/pivot table.  When I insert a slicer for employees and filter down to one name, I see that 6 rows have 'no' and 10 have 'yes', but when I switch back to the table and use the filter column functionality on the table itself, all 16 rows have 'yes' in them for the same employee.  How is that possible?  As far as I know, this sheet is not connected to any datasource and the table was selected when I inserted the pivot and I confirmed the name of the table I'm actually looking at (sorry, at which I was looking =]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I had previously opened and pivoted an older version of the same spreadsheet.  When creating the pivot table for the later version, some cache must have existed that it built the pivot off of instead of the newest data.  By hitting the 'refresh' button on the options tab under PivotTable Tools in the ribbon, my pivot was updated to the proper data.

Comment: That is an important aspect of how Pivot Tables work in Excel. When you create a subsequent pivot table (or chart) based on the same data as an exiting pivot table/chart, you are asked whether (or not)you wish to share this cache between the tables/charts.

Comment: @pnuts: True; but the correct answer to provide is that dictated by the business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the slicer you insert is present in your pivot table filter area. Then only it will work properly. E.g If you insert a slicer for Employees Name, That field should exist in your pivot table filter area as well.

Answer (score 0):

The mismatch in values may occur due to change in format in which the data is stored. Though the format is given as number it is only for display purpose and it may still be stored in text only.So we can use value function in the formula so that the data is actually stored as number and then when pivot is created it will correctly display the values.